# Jmeter randomization for file upload

Tags: templates, jmeter, multipartform-data, mime-types

I am using jmeter script for testing some application. There are some templates in my local. I want to to upload them as a file. I can give the file path and MIME type as well for a single file. However I want jmeter to randomly pick a template from the specified path while execution. Is there a way for this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is going for [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter)

With regards to MIME type it can be determined using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) in the runtime like:

```
${__groovy(new File('/path/to/file.extension).toURL().openConnection().getContentType(),)}
```

Also you might want to reconsider your approach because tests need to be [repeatable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeatability) and "randomization" isn't very compatible with repeatability.